# new.target property behaves unexpected in bound functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was reading about the ECMAScript 2015 new.target property. I thought it was interesting, I could configure a function using the new operator, and then call it by a normal call. But for some reason, this doesn't seem to work. This is my test code.

```
function Test(newConfig) {
  if(new.target){
    if(Test2 !== undefined){
      console.log(new.target === Test2);// why does this give false
      console.log(new.target === Test);// why does this give true
    }
    let mergedConfig = {};
    Object.assign(mergedConfig, newConfig || {}, new.target.config || {})
    let fn = Test.bind({config: mergedConfig});
    fn.config = mergedConfig;
    return fn;
  } else {
     // do something with this.config
     return this.config.a + this.config.b;
  }
}

// initial configuration
// the first time I'm calling the Test function, so new.target === Test
var Test2 = new Test({
  a: 'a'
});
// further configuration
// the second time I'm calling the Test2 function.
// Now, new.target !== Test2, but new.target === Test.
// This is what seems weird to me.
let Test3 = new Test2({b: 'b'});

// normal call
// new.target === undefined
let result = Test3();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you were reading, or what you mean by "*configure a function using the new operator, and then call it by a normal call*", but it looks like you're confusing it with the `this` keyword. Please explain why you expected to get `Test2` there in the first place.

Comment: `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'Test2' before initialization`. Did you mean to declare `Test2` with `var`? `if(Test2 !== undefined)` is not a reliable way to check if `Test2` has been initialized or is in the TDZ.

Comment: You're right. It should be var. I changed the code a bit from my real test code, to make the issue clearer and ECMAScript 6-like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new.target` does not always refer to the called function. Rather, it refers to the function whose `.prototype` property should be used as the prototype for the new instance (so that superclasses can create the right thing).

The `.bind()` method does create special "bound function" objects whose only purpose it is to call the original function with the provided `this` value and partially applied arguments list. They don't even have a `.prototype` property - which should make clear that they are not an appropriate value for `new.target`. And indeed, their [[[construct]] method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget) is specified to use the original function in place of the bound function.

---

So what should you do here? Of course, "using `new` to configure functions" should be avoided in production code, but it's a nice experiment. I would suggest to avoid `bind` here and instead make use of closures:

```
function makeTest(config) {
    return function ConfiguredTest(newConfig) {
        if (new.target) {
            let mergedConfig = {};
            Object.assign(mergedConfig, newConfig || {}, config) // I presume you want to swap the latter two
            return makeTest(mergedConfig);
        } else {
            // use `config` here
            return config.a + config.b;
        }
    };
}
const Test = makeTest({});

// like before
let Test2 = new Test(…)
let Test3 = new Test2(…)
Test3()
```

Comment: I like your thorough response. Thanks.